# Why does it displays a None in the Output

Tags: python-3.x

I get a None for my output of the following code and I don't know why it is?
Can someone explain me why it is and how it can be fixed?
Here's the code,

```
def randomQuestions():
        q1 = 1
        q2 = 2
        for i in range(1):
            if random.randint(1,2)==1:
                a1=int(input(print("Please Enter a Number that is not prime: ",end="")))
                if a1>1:
                    for i in range (2,a1):
                        if (a1%i)==0:
                            print("Correct",a1,"is Not a prime number")
                            break
                    else:
                        print("Incorrect",a1,"is a Prime number")
                else:
                    print("Incorrect",a1,"is a Prime number")
            else:
                a2=int(input(print("Please Enter a Number that is positive: ",end="")))
                if a2>0:
                    print("Correct",a2,"is Positive")
                elif a2==0:
                    print(a2,'Is neither Positive Nor Negative')
                else:
                    print('Incorrect',a2,'is Not Positive')
    randomQuestions()
```

Here's the output;

```
Please Enter a Number that is not prime: None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` function already prints the message for input so you don't need a print function inside that. It displays None because print function returns None. Change

```
int(input(print("Please Enter a Number that is positive: ")))
```

to

```
int(input("Please Enter a Number that is positive: "))
```

Do that for the other input as well.

If you want the input to be entered on a new line, you can also do

```
int(input("Please Enter a Number that is positive: \n"))
```

Comment: @ayban Appreciate your answer :) But now it gives the following error;
TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: That's true, you need to remove `end=""` too.

Comment: @ayban It works :) Now I have understand what is the error I made. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove print statement.

```
def randomQuestions():
            q1 = 1
            q2 = 2
            for i in range(1):
                if random.randint(1,2)==1:
                    a1=int(input("Please Enter a Number that is not prime: "))

                    if a1>1:
                        for i in range (2,a1):
                            if (a1%i)==0:
                                print("Correct",a1,"is Not a prime number")
                                break
                        else:
                            print("Incorrect",a1,"is a Prime number")
                    else:
                        print("Incorrect",a1,"is a Prime number")
                else:
                    a2=int(input("Please Enter a Number that is positive: "))

                    if a2>0:
                        print("Correct",a2,"is Positive")
                    elif a2==0:
                        print(a2,'Is neither Positive Nor Negative')
                    else:
                        print('Incorrect',a2,'is Not Positive')
```

Comment: Fixed it :) Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use print wrapper for your input.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Also, it may not be a be a bad idea to do a NoneType check before proceeding, but the code below should get you working.

```
import random


def randomQuestions():
    q1 = 1
    q2 = 2

    for i in range(1):
        if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
            a1 = int(input("Please Enter a Number that is not prime: "))
            if a1 > 1:
                for i in range (2, a1):
                    if (a1 % i) == 0:
                        print("Correct", a1, "is Not a prime number")
                        break
                else:
                    print("Incorrect", a1, "is a Prime number")
            else:
                print("Incorrect", a1, "is a Prime number")
        else:
            a2 = int(input("Please Enter a Number that is positive: "))
            if a2 > 0:
                print("Correct", a2, "is Positive")
            elif a2 == 0:
                print(a2, 'Is neither Positive Nor Negative')
            else:
                print('Incorrect', a2, 'is Not Positive')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    randomQuestions()
```